# VBA Table header name does not change

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel with macros, every time a button is clicked, 2 new columns are added to an existing table and header of these columns is to be set. It works for the first addition but fails to change the name thereafter even though the columns are being added as required.

```
Sub Add()

Dim lst as ListObject
Dim h as Long
Dim hdrs

hdrs = Array("Value 1", "Value 2")

Set lst =  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

With lst
    For h = 0 To 1
        .ListColumns.Add
        .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = hdrs(h)
    Next h
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot have two column headers the same. Remember, the column header labels are used in structured table references for formulas so two identical headers would make a ambiguous reference. e.g. `=sum(Table1[Value 1])`

Comment: @Jeeped Got it. Thank you!